# Edit activities in a period with a particular state- Symfony

Tags: symfony

I would like to edit activities in a period with a particular state. 0-inactive, 1-active, 2-verify, 3-closed. If the period has state of 1 then the user would be allowed to edit. Otherwise they will get an error. While testing even if state is @ 1, the user still gets the error. The periodid is a foreign key in activity table while state is another table with period id has the primary key. I have this in the

**Repository**

```
public function findBytransid($payrollperiodid)
{
    $repository=$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity');
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->select('a','pp');
    $qb->Join('a.payrollperiodid','pp');
    $qb->where('pp.state = :state');
    $qb->setParameter('state', 1);

    return $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**Controller**

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity')
    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->innerJoin('a.sectionid', 's')
    ->innerJoin('s.farmid', 'f')
    ->where('a.transid=:id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

$state = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Activity')->findBytransid($id);

if (!$entity) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activity entity.');
} elseif ($state) {
    $this->addFlash('error', 'ERROR! Cannot edit, this activity is active.');
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('activity'));
} else {

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

**edit**
For instance the user clicks on an activity that period matches with a state of 1 then it brings them to the edit form page else error you can edit this activity

Comment: Please, specify clearly with what data(db record) you test, what is expected and actual results. What do you mean by "user gets error"? What he should get?
Also in your controller not clear what is $entity ?

Comment: Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to :

- put your `findBytransid` function in the repository. Maybe another
  controller would need it.
- check you `findBytransid` function which is not bound to one activity but will return an array of activity. The function is named `findBytransid` but it never use the sayed id.
- use correct name for you variables : `findBytransid()` is bound to Activity Repository but, you named its return state
- Write a request for state and activity :

  ```
  public function findActivityByTransId ($id) {
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a'); // because the function is placed in the repository
      $qb->innerJoin('a.sectionid', 's')
      ->innerJoin('s.farmid', 'f')
      ->join('a.payrollperiodid','pp')
      ->where('a.transid=:id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id)
      ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
  }
  ```

Then in the controller :

```
// ....
$activity = $repository->findActivityByTransId($id);

if ($activity == null) {
     throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activity entity.');
} else {
    if ($activity->getParyrollPeriodId() == null || $activity->getParyrollPeriodId()->getState() != 1) {
           $this->addFlash('error', 'ERROR! Cannot edit, this activity is active.');
           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('activity')); 
} else {
     ....
}
```

Note : Since you only need one entity you would take benefit of doctrine lazy loading capabilities and built in fetching method using a

```
$activity = $repository->find($id); //if transid is the primary key otherwise use findBy(array(...))
```

Hope this helps